# How to make my CSS responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

He I am working on a standard template for my applications. I suck in CSS and I have a headache working on making a good responsive design.

Now this is my idea:

[image]

This is how it works out:

[demo](http://paperboat.tk/dev/webapplicatie/2.3/)

Now with some java-script I can probably do this but if this is possible in CSS it would be nice. My question is how can I make my design with just HTML and CSS.

A jsFiddle just fore fun:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3Xus/1/)

My css:

```
body{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS",sans-serif;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

#content{
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #5adc23;
}

input[type="button"]{
    border:2px outset rgb(166, 166, 166);
    display:inline-block;
}

input[type="button"]:hover{
    border:2px inset rgb(166, 166, 166);
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#mainbar{
    height: 31px;
    background-color: rgb(109, 164, 227);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(39, 162, 207) 1%, rgb(63, 181, 224) 36%, rgb(63, 181, 224) 64%, rgb(39, 162, 207) 100%);
}

    #mainbar_border{
        height: 100%;
        border-bottom:1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
        font-family: 'Courier New', serif; 
        font-size: 21px; 
    }

#mainmenu{
    width: 40px;
    height: 96%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    float: left;
}

    #mainmenu_border{
        height: 99%;
        padding: 4px;
        padding-top: 46px;
        padding-bottom: 19px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-left-width: 1px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-left-style: solid;
    }

        #mainmenu_item_container{
            list-style-type:none;
        }

#content_app{
    float: left;
    width: 88%;
    height: 96%;
}

    #content_app_border{
        height: 99%;
        padding: 4px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-left-width: 1px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-left-style: solid;
        border-right-width: 1px;
        border-right-style: solid;
    }
```

my html:

```
<div id='content' class='invoer'>    
    <div id='mainbar'>
        <div id='mainbar_border'>
            Mainbar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='mainmenu'>
        <div id='mainmenu_border'>
            <ul id='mainmenu_item_container'>
                <li><input type='button' value='Load content' title='load some more shit to test the resposive design' id='btn' action='loadmoreshit' /></li>
                <li>button</li>
                <li>button</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='content_app'>
        <div id='content_app_border'>
            content
            <br>
                <br>
                    <br>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfNCp/) that will give you a rough version of the layout your diagram is looking for.  From here you could use media queries as Jefferson suggested to create alternate versions for mobile devices. One tip - the divs that are here should be used just as a skeleton, I would not try to style them. If you start adding borders and some other styles to them the edges will no longer line up. Here is the CSS and HTML -

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="left_nav">Left Navigation</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>

div {
    position: absolute;
}

#header {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
}

#left_nav {
    top: 40px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: red;
}

#content {
    top: 40px;
    left: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: green;
}
```

UPDATE: After your last comment I worked on this a bit more. First off, here are you criteria as I understand them:

1. The left menu and the content should start 100px down from the top to accomodate the header.
2. The left manu and content should extend at least to the bottom of the page.
3. If either the left menu or content overflows beyond the bottom of the page, then:
   a. They should both expand down so that their height is equal.
   b. The entire page should scroll, instead of individual panels.

With this in mind, I was unable to produce all of these effects purely with CSS and HTML, so it looks like Javascript may be required here.  I've updated [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6hsF/3/) so that overflow from the `#main_container` is shown.  At this point the solution accomplishes 1, 2 and 3b.  To accomplish 3a I added this javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var body_height = $("body").height();
    var body_scroll = $("body").get(0).scrollHeight;
    var menu_height = $("#left_nav").height();
    var content_height = $("#content").height();

    if(body_scroll > body_height && (menu_height != content_height)) {
        if(menu_height > content_height) {
            $("#content").css("height", (menu_height + "px"));
        } else {
            $("#left_nav").css("height", (content_height + "px"));
        }
    }
});
```

All this does is ensure that the `#left_nav` and `#content` are the same height.  It does use JQuery, so if you're not using JQuery you'll have to rewrite it for pure Javascript.  Though, if you aren't using JQuery, I'd highly recommend you get it [here](http://jquery.com/download/).  It'll make your life a lot easier.  Also take note of the `#spike` div, which provides an example of adding a "border" div inside one of the positioning elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that when there is more content the #content and #left_nav have to expand. See http://jsfiddle.net/hfNCp/1/

Comment: Well after some editing I Made your example dynamically expand the height to. But now I have to make a min-height of the total html height - 40px of the header. So Javascript it is then!

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/x6hsF/1/; I think it may get closer to what you're looking for.  This uses a container around the content and left nav with `overflow: auto;`, and the left nav and content are set to `min-height: 100%;`, so they will always expand to at least the bottom of the screen, but then the container will generate a scrollbar if the content expands beyond that.

Comment: one little problem: http://paperboat.tk/dev/webapplicatie/2.3/ I try to make borders but the border div wil not expand 100% height!?

Comment: Ok thanks however I found a solution for the borders but still thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a css framework lite [twitter.github.io/bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), [foundation.zurb.com](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [gumbyframework.com](http://gumbyframework.com/)

This way you don't need to build everything from the ground. You'll get a lot of styling from start like responsive scaffolding, forms, tables, buttons, menus etc.

As a beginner it can be easier to build on something nice and good and learn from that.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of getting your designs responsive is using [media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/).

This requires only html and css. You could fix your own media queries, or use premade responsive frameworks. Such as [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).

The Media Queries in CSS3 look at the capability of the device, and you can use them to check for all kinds of things. For example:
- width and height (of the browser window)
- device width and height
- orientation – for example is a phone in landscape or portrait mode?
- resolution

You can then style your html according to these capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Using an existing framework like Bootstrap is probably a good idea if you are uncomfortable doing it yourself. What you describe above though doesn't really need media queries since it's really a fairly basic fluid layout.

The following achieves what you want in a basic form

html:

```
<div id="content" class="invoer">
    <div id="mainbar">
        Mainbar
    </div>
    <div id="mainmenu">
            <ul>
                <li>button</li>
                <li>button</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content_app">
            <br>blablabla content
            <hr>
            <br>blablabla content
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#content {
    background:#00E113
}
#mainbar {
    width:98%;
    height:40px;
    background:#00ACD9;
    color:#fff;
    padding:1%;
}
#mainmenu {
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
#content_app {
    margin-left:140px;
}
```

Here I used an absolutely positioned mainmenu so that it doesn't affect the width of any surrounding elements. Then set a margin-left on the content_app to allow enough space for the mainmenu.

Try it here
http://jsfiddle.net/PMJBc/2/